# Faster Wheels & Tyres for my Cyclocross bike

Tags: tire, wheels, speed

I ride a cyclocross bike for commuting but want it to go faster! Instead of buying a new road bike, I'm thinking about new wheels & tyres. My journey is pretty flat at the moment.

The currents wheels are 700 * 35 and its using a 9 speed cassette with disk brakes.

So my question is, what are my options do I have , how small a tyre can I fit to the 35 wheel ?

Comment: Quite a lot of tyres listed here: https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/; it's not just the size which counts

Comment: What is the tooth count of your current crank? Are you currently overspinning while trying to increase your speed?

Comment: no over spinning, 50-34

Answer (score 2):

Its not the size of the tyre, its the knobliness and the rolling resistance.

Assuming 35 is the tyre size then you have a 15-24 mm rim, based on [this DT Swiss PDF](https://pictures.dtswiss.com/uploads/WXD10000000866S/MAN_WXD10000000866S_WEB_ZZ_001.pdf)  and maybe could go as far as a 20mm tyre.  This is rim width dependant though.

Realistically, a smooth 28-25 mm tyre will give you a more comfortable ride than a narrow tyre, and will roll just as fast if not faster.

CX bikes are fine for commuting - a road bike might be slightly faster but often takes away things like fender/mudguard mounts, or rack mounts which add to the overall comfort of your ride.

Comment: So I could get a 28mm tyre, what are your thoughts on these ? - http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/schwalbe-g-one-speed-road-tyre-microskin/rp-prod154972 and would it be worth changing the wheels from these ? - http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/mavic-xm319-disc-mtb-rim-2015/rp-prod71060

Comment: That's just the rim, not the whole wheel. You should be able to fit lighter (and more aerodynamic) wheels, which would be good if you wanted to switch between CX and road tyres without a lot of work